# Fit an image in a div

Tags: css

I am trying to fit an image into my div,this is the div.

```
#Div3 {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #906;
    width: 960px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 202px;
}
html > body # Div3 {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 203px;
}
```

The image css is as follows.

```
/* rotator in-page placement */
div.rotator {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 202px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: none;
} /* rotator css */
div.rotator ul li {
    float: center;
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
}

div.rotator ul li.show {
    z-index: 500
}
```

On my html page i have this.

```
<div id="Div3" class="rotator">
    <ul>
        <li class="show"><a href="#link1"><img src="./first.jpg" width="960" height="202"  alt="pic1" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#link2"><img src="./second.jpg" width="960" height="202"  alt="pic2" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#link3"><img src="./third.jpg" width="960" height="202"  alt="pic3" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#link4"><img src="./fifth.jpg" width="960" height="202"  alt="pic4" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The result is that the image displays but do not fit perfectly into the div as i would have wanted.What could be the problem?.

Comment: Could you post an example of your problem on JSfiddle.com or something similar? It would help lots! :-)

Comment: float: center; doesn't exist. Only left and right

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/objectiveme/MLCwc/

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you need to reset the standard margins / paddings:

```
li, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Second I don´t think your positioning is correct, `float:center` does not exist and you don´t float anyway when you use `absolute` positioning.

It also might help to add a specific position:

```
div.rotator ul li {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Oh, and `list-style` has no spaces in it...

Answer (score 0):

Expand your div by 1px in each direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.rotator ul li {
height:202px;
}
```